# calling .cpp function in .m and .mm file, error

Tags: c++, objective-c, mixing

i am trying to integrate my own small cpp project into a big objective-c project. I have compiled my own project into a .dylib file and added into the big project, and .h file is included.  But in order to follow the legacy i have to call my function from a .m file in the big project.

i know that .m file can not call cpp functions so what i have tried is to include my cpp .h file in another .mm file, then in my .m file i include the header file to the .mm file. here is what i did:

A.mm  (i created this file together with the header)

```
#import "A.h"
#include "mycppfunc.h"
int ParseFile(char * filename)
{
    ....(using cpp functions)
    return 0;
}
```

A.h

```
int ParseFile(char* filename);
```

B.mm (originally in the big project)

```
#import "B.h"
#import "A.h"
.... (original codes in B.mm)
```

B.h

```
#import "C.h"
....
```

C.m (originally in the big project, i have to call my own functions from here due to legacy)

```
#import "C.h"
#import "B.h"
....
- (IBAction) call_my_proj: (id) sender
{
    ....
    ParseFile("myfile.txt");
}
```

C.h

```
.... (this file is un-changed)
```

When i compile, i got this error:

```
Implicit declaration of function 'ParseFile' is invalid in C99
```

Can anyone help me explain where it went wrong? Can it be due to the circular reference to different header file (but i can not change it since it affects other peoples code). how can i get rid of this error? any help is highly appreciated! thanks.

Comment: Are you including `A.h` anywhere (e.g. from C.h or C.m)? That's the only place that `ParseFile` is defined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need to include `A.h` from `C.h` or `C.m`.

But, because the functions defined in `A.mm` are being compiled with a (Obj)C++ compiler, you might need to make them callable from C. You do this using [C linkage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1041866/in-c-source-what-is-the-effect-of-extern-c). Then `ParseFile()` should be callable from the C.m file. For instance, in the header file:

```
extern "C"
{
   int ParseFile(const char *);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Nathan, this seems to make some progress. i added #ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
    
    int ParseFile(char * filename);
    
#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif

Comment: Thanks Nathan, this seems to make some progress. i added #ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
    
    int ParseFile(char * filename);
    
#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
and when i compile i don't get the same error anymore. however, it seems to mess up the namespace in a cpp file (D.cpp) which is called by A.mm (D.h is included in A.mm). i got error "redefinition of '<namespace name>' as a different kind of symbol", and some class names become "undeclared"---i got "use of undeclared identifier xxxx " error. Do you have any idea why it became so?

Comment: I would first look at the namespaces being used in D.cpp/D.h to see if there is a naming conflict with ParseFile or some other function.

Answer (score 1):

You need to `#include "A.h"` in `C.m`. You are calling `ParseFile()` in `C.m`.

Comment: thanks. but once i included A.h in C.m i got the linker error

Comment: Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_ParseFile", referenced from:
      -[...this is where i call the ParseFile function] in C.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Answer (score 0):

Rename extension of all your .m files to .mm. This way you can directly call cpp functions in your objective-C classes without any wrappers.

Comment: thanks Lambda1 but i can not change the extension as it affects the code written by other people. what can i do instead?